# How to open browser with open console

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I like to open in selenium browser with console window on. I tried with F12 keyDown keyUp and send keys to body and shortcut like CTRL + SHIFT + i/k like this but its not working on Firefox or Chrome. It's only return error or doing nothing is posible way to do this? I think about make webdriver profile but not know argument to do this or use JS?

```
//firefox
CharSequence sequence = Keys.chord(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT, "k");
builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(sequence).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```